# JQuery menu from sprites

Tags: jquery, css

I recently inherited a code-base with a web application. This application has a menu built with a TABLE element and some JQuery. That code does not work like it should. The menus behave oddly. Regardless, the existing code looks like the following:

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style="width:500px;">
  <tr>
    <td id="home" class="homeA" onclick="return navto('/home.html');">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="about" class="aboutA">
      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="aboutMenu">
          <li class="usA" onmouseover="hoverOver(this);" onmouseout="hoverOut(this);" onclick="return navto('/AboutUs.html');">&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="teamA" onmouseover="hoverOver(this);" onmouseout="hoverOut(this);" onclick="return navto('/team.html');">&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="contactA" onmouseover="hoverOver(this);" onmouseout="hoverOut(this);" onclick="return navto('/contact.php');">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td id="teams" class="teamsA">
     <div class="menu">
       <ul class="teamsMenu">
         <li class="team1A" onmouseover="hoverOver(this);" onmouseout="hoverOut(this);" onclick="return navto('/Teams/Team1.html');">&nbsp;</li>
         <li class="team2A" onmouseover="hoverOver(this);" onmouseout="hoverOut(this);" onclick="return navto('/Teams/Team2.html');">&nbsp;</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </td>
</table>
```

I want to replace this table with a DIV. While I'm at it, I want to use a better JQuery menu control. My challenge is, I need to use sprites. Each menu header, as well as each item in the menu, is represented as an image. The image changes when the user hovers over an item. This leads me to the following question:

What menu control can I use, while still using sprites? Or, can anyone explain how I can create a menu using JQuery and sprites?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sprites, you don't need to rely on jQuery.
CSS events hover/active should do the trick.

But if you really want to use jQuery, this link will help you :
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/use-sprites-to-create-an-awesomeness-filled-navigation-menu/

Comment: But how do I create a menu without JQuery? The current menu is not behaving propertly.